# Constantly check if timeline is stopped - trigger action

Tags: java, javafx, timeline

I've got a timeline that runs for 120 seconds. It does stop the animation after 120 seconds. I need a way to check whether the timeline has been stopped after the 120 seconds so I can create an alertbox or open a new window.

I know about timeline.getStatus(), but I need to be checking that somewhere for it to return "Stopped".

Comment: [`timeline.setOnFinished(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished-javafx.event.EventHandler-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James_D said in the question comments, the class `Animation` has a method `setOnFinished(EventHandler<ActionEvent>)`. Since `Timeline` extends `Animation` you can use it with your timeline. This `EventHandler` will be called when the animation stops (as the name suggests). Alternatively you can listen to the status property and react when it changes to `STOPPED`.